# Android 4.2 background SMS

Tags: android, android-widget, android-service

I wish to make widget that will monitor my balance with SMS query.
Nexus 4 notifies about SMS now. But I wish it to not notify and constanly query my balance.
These SMS are free for me.

Is there way to implement such service/widget ?

Comment: It is hard to know what you are asking here.

Comment: The problem is that where to text and with what datais going to be different for every carrier.  If your carrier provides an SMS query it that would be fairly easy.  But you couldn't write this and expect it to work for anyone on another carrier.

Comment: Please clarify your question. What balance are you referring to? Do you just need the ability to read your own SMS messages from an app?

Comment: I wish to make my personal widget and it will work with only my carrier. It will send SMS to number 111 with word balance. carrier will send SMS back from number 111 with balance that I wish my service to parse and notify and me if balance is low. Android 4.2 notifies user when SMS is sent. It asks app is sending SMS. OK? It is not acceptable for such service.

Answer (score 1):

You should register your app as reciever for "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" broadcast event.

There are many difficulties to correct handling of sms, try to read [this article](http://www.apriorit.com/our-company/dev-blog/227-handle-sms-on-android)